# Order of a group and kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f:H \implies H'$ be a group homomorphism. If $|H|=20$ and |H'|=16. What is the order of $ker(f)$ if $f$ is a non-trivial homomorphism?

My attempt is : $ker(f)=\{a\in H| f(a)=h^{16} for h\in H'\}$. Thus, such $a$ will have order $1,2,4$ because I have to make sure that the orders divide $|H|$. Thus, the $|ker(f)|=3$. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer isn't correct, since by Lagrange's Theorem, the order of a subgroup of $H$ must have order dividing $|H| = 20$; but $3 \nmid 20$.

By the first isomorphism theorem,

$$H/\ker{f} \cong f(H) \leq H'$$

In particular, $|\ker{f}|$ is a divisor of $|H| = 20$ and $20/|\ker f|$ is a divisor of $|H'| = 16$. The divisors of $20$ are $\{1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20\}$, and we can rule out everything but $5, 10, 20$. Since $f$ is non-trivial, we can get rid of $20$, so the options are $5$ and $10$.

Comment: Yes, I get where my mistake is. But I had a question: Since we get the order of the kernel will be 2, that is it will contain the elements with order 5 and 10. But how do we know there are only two subgroups of order 5 and 10. Why can't I have 2 subgroups of order 5 and two of order 10